# Shuffle array while spacing repeating elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, shuffle

I'm trying to write a function that shuffles an array, which contains repeating elements, but ensures that repeating elements are not too close to one another.

This code works but seems inefficient to me:

```
function shuffledArr = distShuffle(myArr, myDist)
% this function takes an array myArr and shuffles it, while ensuring that repeating 
% elements are at least myDist elements away from on another    

% flag to indicate whether there are repetitions within myDist
reps = 1;
while reps 

    % set to 0 to break while-loop, will be set to 1 if it doesn't meet condition
    reps = 0;  

    % randomly shuffle array
    shuffledArr = Shuffle(myArr);

    % loop through each unique value, find its position, and calculate the distance to the next occurence
    for x = 1:length(unique(myArr))
        % check if there are any repetitions that are separated by myDist or less
       if any(diff(find(shuffledArr == x)) <= myDist)
           reps = 1;
       break;
   end
end
end
```

This seems suboptimal to me for three reasons:

1) It may not be necessary to repeatedly shuffle until a solution has been found.

2) This while loop will go on forever if there is no possible solution (i.e. setting myDist to be too high to find a configuration that fits). Any ideas on how to catch this in advance?

3) There must be an easier way to determine the distance between repeating elements in an array than what I did by looping through each unique value.

I would be grateful for answers to points 2 and 3, even if point 1 is correct and it is possible to do this in a single shuffle.

Comment: If there is, for example, 8 possibles shuffling for a given array do your algorithm have to find only one solution or randomly give you one shuffling with a probability 1/8 ? The second case is way harder to reach.

Comment: Do you know bogey sort? It is trying to sort an array by randomising it and then check if it has been sorted, if not, randomise it again. This is, obviously, not the sorting algorithm anyone should pick, and yet what you do sounds remarkably similar (bit weaker, admitted). Is the randomisation nessecary? or would, e.g. a maximisation of `sum(abs(diff(shuffledArr)))` be sufficient?

Comment: @obchardon any solution is fine.

Comment: @NickyMattsson: Never heard of bogey sort, thanks for the hint! Randomisation in this case is necessary, because this is to create a random order of stimuli for a psychological experiment. maximising the distances would unfortunately not satisfy my goal to make stimulus presentation naturalistic (i.e. pseudo-random).

Comment: If the array is not too large you could generate all permutations, keep those that satisfiy the minimum distance, and pick one. Is that an option?

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the suggestion! Would that be better than the solution I proposed above? It seems that I'm at least stopping when I reach a permutation that satisfies the minimum distance, whereas in your case I would have to generate all of them! Am I missing something?

Comment: @galliwuzz Yes, all of them. That would only be practical for array length less than about 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find one possible solution you could use something like that:

```
x = [1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   4   5   5   6   7   8   9];
n = numel(x);
dist = 3;           %minimal distance
uni = unique(x);    %get the unique value
his = histc(x,uni); %count the occurence of each element
s = [sortrows([uni;his].',2,'descend'), zeros(length(uni),1)];

xr = [];            %the vector that will contains the solution

%the for loop that will maximize the distance of each element
for ii = 1:n
    s(s(:,3)<0,3) = s(s(:,3)<0,3)+1;
    s(1,3) = s(1,3)-dist;
    s(1,2) = s(1,2)-1; 
    xr = [xr s(1,1)];
    s = sortrows(s,[3,2],{'descend','descend'})
end

if any(s(:,2)~=0)
    fprintf('failed, dist is too big')
end
```

Result:

```
xr = [3   1   2   5   3   1   2   4   3   6   7   8   3   9   5   1   2   3]
```

Explaination:

I create a vector `s` and at the beggining `s` is equal to:

```
s =

   3   5   0
   1   3   0
   2   3   0
   5   2   0
   4   1   0
   6   1   0
   7   1   0
   8   1   0
   9   1   0

%col1 = unique element; col2 = occurence of each element, col3 = penalities
```

At each iteration of our for-loop we choose the element with the maximum occurence since this element will be harder to place in our array.

Then after the first iteration s is equal to:

```
s =

   1   3   0  %1 is the next element that will be placed in our array.
   2   3   0
   5   2   0
   4   1   0
   6   1   0
   7   1   0
   8   1   0
   9   1   0
   3   4  -3  %3 has now 5-1 = 4 occurence and a penalities of -3 so it won't show up the next 3 iterations.
```

at the end every number of the second column should be equal to 0, if it's not the minimal distance was too big.

Comment: Excellent approach. As I need a pseudo-random order for my experiment I slightly adapted your code by shuffling all the acceptable answers in each iteration  (i.e. all the rows of s with penalty = 0 and the maximum number of occurrences).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is sufficient to check the following condition to prevent infinite loops:

```
[~,num, C] = mode(myArr);
N = numel(C);
assert( (myDist<=N)  || (myDist-N+1) * (num-1) +N*num <= numel(myArr),...
'Shuffling impossible!');
```

Assume that `myDist` is `2` and we have the following data:

```
[4 6 5 1 6 7 4 6]
```

We can find the the mode , `6`, with its occurence, `3`. We arrange `6`s separating them by `2 = myDist`  blanks:

```
6 _ _ 6 _ _6
```

There must be `(3-1) * myDist = 4` numbers to fill the blanks. Now we have five more numbers so the array can be shuffled.

The problem becomes more complicated if we have multiple modes. For example  for this array `[4 6 5 1 6 7 4 6 4]` we have `N=2` modes: `6` and `4`. They can be arranged as:

```
6 4 _ 6 4 _ 6 4
```

We have 2 blanks and three more numbers `[ 5 1 7]` that can be used to fill the blanks. If for example we had  only one number `[ 5]` it was impossible to fill the blanks and we couldn't shuffle the array.

For the third point you can use sparse matrix to accelerate the computation (My initial testing in Octave shows that it is more efficient):

```
function shuffledArr = distShuffleSparse(myArr, myDist)
    [U,~,idx] = unique(myArr);
    reps = true;
    while reps 
        S = Shuffle(idx);
        shuffledBin = sparse ( 1:numel(idx), S, true, numel(idx) + myDist, numel(U) );
        reps = any (diff(find(shuffledBin)) <= myDist);
    end
    shuffledArr = U(S);
end
```

Alternatively you can use [sub2ind](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) and [sort](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) instead of sparse matrix:

```
function shuffledArr = distShuffleSparse(myArr, myDist)
    [U,~,idx] = unique(myArr);
    reps = true;
    while reps 
        S = Shuffle(idx);
        f = sub2ind ( [numel(idx) + myDist, numel(U)] , 1:numel(idx), S );
        reps = any (diff(sort(f)) <= myDist);
    end
    shuffledArr = U(S);
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think obchardon's approach is more suitable here, but this made me aware of the advantages of sparse matrices!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that doesn't use sparse matrix.